# PHP: How to get the date of day before yesterday?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the date of day before yesterday in PHP.

But I don't know how to do it.

Please help me.

Comment: `new DateTime('2 days ago')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') , PHP_EOL;
```

PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. what is the differrence between this and strtotime ? i looked to strtotime() it is much easier to use.

Comment: strtotime works with simple numeric timestamps (number of sseconds since PHP's basedate). DateTime is a PHP dateTime object, which provides an OO approach to working with date/time values, plus a lot of sophisticated tools (since PHP 5.3.0) for working with timezones, intervals and periods of time

Comment: then it means is it much faster ?

Comment: It isn't faster, but it's a lot more flexible... and can handle a wider range of dates than the standard date functions in 32-bit PHP (with its 2032 limitation), because dateTime objects use 64-bits internally.

Answer (score 19):

There is **[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)** function for this process. Use the following code:

```
strtotime('-2 day');
```

And please research your question on Google, before asking.

Comment: Will that set time section to 00:00? Or will keep hours:minutes from "now"?

Comment: @przemo_li Yes, it will keep time gathered from now

Comment: @przemo_li if you want time to be 00:00 you can do `strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days')))`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    print date("F j, Y", time() - 172800);
?>
```

There are 172800 seconds in 48 hours. The first argument of the date function is the formatting string; see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for other formatting options.

Comment: There aren't necessarily 24 hours in a day or 60 seconds in a minute. There exists such nasty things as daylight saving time and leap seconds. Time is hard :)

Comment: Uh... I don't know how to deal with that. Perhaps `date("F j, Y",strtotime('-2 day'));` would work.