# How to find the day before yesterday date from current date? using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get date of day before yesterday?

Comment: are you using jquery date picker?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885815/php-how-to-get-the-date-of-day-before-yesterday

Answer (score 0):

```
var fromDate = new Date();
fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
 var d = new Date();
 var month = d.getMonth()+1;
 var day = d.getDate();

 var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    (day<10 ? '0' : '') + (day-2);
 alert(output);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do like this:**

```
resultdate.setDate(resultdate.getDate() - 2);
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
   var dateString = new Date(); // date string
    var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
    var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()-2);// create new increased date
```